# Is it possible to Drag&drop any file into QT application?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

is it possible to enable Drag&Drop in QT applications?
I mean I want to Drag any file to my application and I want to **read** its
**filename** and path.

I have been watching examples of drag&drop searching for
additional informations but I only figured out that drag&drop works
between internal widgets of QT application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt Drag & Drop: Allow dragging files to the application's main window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895302/qt-drag-drop-allow-dragging-files-to-the-applications-main-window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For files dragged over your widget, the QMimeData will have [urls](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html#urls) which are paths to the files.

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html#drag-and-drop-actions :

> The other major use of drag actions is when using a reference type such as text/uri-list, where the dragged data are actually references to files or objects.

Comment: Ok, the functions seems to work and the application responds for dragging. But what about the icon when the object is dragging - I mean I still have a crossed circle - do I need to change the icon myself? Is this correct?

Comment: @mateusz_s You need to implement `dragEnterEvent` and accept the event

Comment: Ok, it finally works, but it seems the problem was in running of application. I was running it from QT - and then it didn't work. But when I run it as *.exe file from windows it works fine. thanks.

Comment: Note that on macos, there may be issues getting the path of *.webloc files, which seem to come in as the URL they contain, rather than the path to the file.  This has been filed as a bug here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59444