# Qt Drag & Drop: Add support for dragging files to the application's main window

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

A lot of applications allow users to drag a file or files to the application's main window.

How do I add support for this feature in my own Qt application?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Overload `dragEnterEvent()` and `dropEvent()` in your `MainWindow` class, and call `setAcceptDrops()` in the constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    ..........
    setAcceptDrops(true);
}

void MainWindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *e)
{
    if (e->mimeData()->hasUrls()) {
        e->acceptProposedAction();
    }
}

void MainWindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent *e)
{
    foreach (const QUrl &url, e->mimeData()->urls()) {
        QString fileName = url.toLocalFile();
        qDebug() << "Dropped file:" << fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: I had to override the `MainWindow::dragMoveEvent()`  method too in which I just `acceptProposedAction()`'d the event. Otherwise it wouldn't work for me.

Comment: For those wanting to drop into container type widgets such as listview etc, you perform on their `viewport()` and not the direct widget itself.

Answer (score 7):

First, check [Qt Reference Documentation: Drag and Drop](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) for the fundamentals, and then take a look at [Drag and Drop of files on QMainWindows](http://wiki.qt.io/Drag_and_Drop_of_files) for the technical stuff. The latter provides a complete example.

Qt also has a bunch of [Drag and Drop examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-draganddrop.html), you might be interested in the [Drop Site](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-draganddrop-dropsite-example.html).