# Qt drop a file | mac os

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qmainwindow, qtgui

I've done many searches (leading me to [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/dnd.html#drag-and-drop-classes) and [that](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Drag_and_Drop_of_files)) and adding a few lines to my classes

#### MainWindow.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QtGui/QDragLeaveEvent>
#include <QtGui/QDragMoveEvent>
#include <QtGui/QDropEvent>
#include <QtCore/QMimeData>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ....
    setAcceptDrops(true);
}

void MainWindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void MainWindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "On Drop Event";
    const QMimeData* mimeData = event->mimeData();

    if (mimeData->hasUrls())
    {
        QStringList pathList;
        QList<QUrl> urlList = mimeData->urls();

        for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size() && i < 32; ++i)
        {
            pathList.append(urlList.at(i).toLocalFile());
        }

        if(openFiles(pathList))
            event->acceptProposedAction();
    }
}
void MainWindow::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent * event)
{
event->acceptProposedAction();
}
void MainWindow::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent* event)
{
    event->accept();
}
```

But I can't drop a file onto my MainWindow (from the finder). It's not that my code crashes or does not compile, it's just that I literally *can't*. No reaction from the `MainWindow`, no highlight, nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt Drag & Drop: Allow dragging files to the application's main window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895302/qt-drag-drop-allow-dragging-files-to-the-applications-main-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you should also be overloading the dragMoveEvent: -

```
void QWidget::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent * event)
```

As the docs state: -

> This event handler is called if a drag is in progress, and when any of the following conditions occur: the cursor enters this widget, the cursor moves within this widget, or a modifier key is pressed on the keyboard while this widget has the focus. The event is passed in the event parameter.

There's an example of a Qt drag and drop [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/draganddrop-dropsite.html). Specifically [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/draganddrop-dropsite-droparea-cpp.html) is a good reference.

Comment: What doesn't work? Have you just added the dragMoveEvent? Are you also accepting the proposed action on the event?

Comment: I accept the proposed action and I still can't drop a file on the MainWindow

Comment: Are you accepting the proposed action in both the enter and move events? Can you change your question to represent what you have now?

Comment: You also need the dragLeave event adding.

Comment: Added, still unable to drop file

Comment: Ok, I was using the wrong function : `event->acceptProposedAction();` instead of `event->accept()` , now it works.

Comment: Great, thanks for the feedback. Good to know I wasn't going crazy ;O)